# adding checkboxes to a listview in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-checkbox

When I run the following code the name of the Checkboxes are coming up as random strings (like `android.widget.CheckBox@43e641b0`.) Also I cannot click those added Checkboxes.

This is my java code:

```
package com.srk.android.rough1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.ListActivity;


public class Rough1Activity extends ListActivity {
   ArrayList<CheckBox> listItems=new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
   ArrayAdapter<CheckBox> adapter;
   private EditText taskNameEditText;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       adapter=new ArrayAdapter<CheckBox>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listItems);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
   }

   public void addItems(View v) {
       taskNameEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TaskName);
       String taskName=taskNameEditText.getText().toString();
       CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);
       cb.setText(taskName);
       listItems.add(cb);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display CheckBoxes as you would add an array of integers or Strings... I suggest a different approach:

```
public class Rough1Activity extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private EditText taskNameEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // I like this layout, but it's your choice
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, listItems);
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // I guessed that you want a multiple choice list from your first layout choice. This is optional, you can remove it.
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        // Here you only need to initialize taskNameEditText once 
        taskNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TaskName);
    }

    public void addItems(View v) {
        // Add the current string in the EditText to the ListView
        adapter.add(taskNameEditText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

You want to have a list of Strings and display the strings with a Checkbox. I changed  your ArrayList and ArrayAdapter to String subtypes to reflex this and the layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` adds the Checkbox features itself. Now the user will see the text they entered in a ListView with checkable rows.

Hope this helps!